# make a field required only if a select has a specific value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this form:

```
<form id="new_field" class="form-horizontal contact-form">
    <div class="form-group" class="colored-text">
        <label for="tipo_field" class="colored-text">Tipologia di campo: </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="tipo_field" name="tipo_field">
            <option value="">Scegli una tipologia di campo</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="alternatives_area" style="display:none;">
        <label class="colored-text">Alternative: </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="alternatives" id="alternatives" style="display: none"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="field_submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Crea</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="undo_new_field"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Esci</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to use validation on it and it works for other fields in the form (excluded from the above code since they are not relevant). What I fail to achieve is to put a rule that makes the textarea `#alternatives` required but only when the `#tipo_field` select value is 2 or 3.

For what I understand I have to use `depends` as [explained in the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) but I cannot spot exactly how to apply it for my requirement.

The js code I have so far is:

```
$('#new_field').validate({
    rules: {
      nome_field: {
        required: true,
      },
      desc_field: {
        required: true,
        
      },
      tipo_field: {
        required: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      nome_field: "Il nome del campo è richiesto",
      desc_field: "La label del campo è richiesta",
      tipo_field: "Per favore scegli una tipologia per questo campo"
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you can use `depends` to meet your requirements. Simply provide an object to `required` which contains the `depends` property, and a function which returns a boolean to determine if the `#alternatives` field is required or not.

I addition, for the validation logic to be triggered when you click the `Crea` button it needs to be a `type="submit"` element, not `type="button"`. Try this:

```js
$('#new_field').validate({
  rules: {
    nome_field: {
      required: true
    },
    desc_field: {
      required: true
    },
    tipo_field: {
      required: true
    },
    alternatives: {
      required: {
        depends: () => parseInt($('#tipo_field').val(), 10) > 1
      }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    nome_field: "Il nome del campo è richiesto",
    desc_field: "La label del campo è richiesta",
    tipo_field: "Per favore scegli una tipologia per questo campo"
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
    element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
  },
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    console.log('valid');
    //form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="new_field" class="form-horizontal contact-form">
  <div class="form-group" class="colored-text">
    <label for="tipo_field" class="colored-text">Tipologia di campo: </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_field" name="tipo_field">
      <option value="">Scegli una tipologia di campo</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="alternatives_area">
    <label class="colored-text">Alternative: </label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="alternatives" id="alternatives"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="field_submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Crea</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="undo_new_field"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Esci</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that I made all the form controls visible in the example, as the logic which toggled them was not included in the original question.

Comment: Thanks Rory. You are right. The hidden field is visible on change of the select.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

following the documentation, you could write:

```
alternatives: {
  required: {
    depends: () => parseInt($('#tipo_field').val(), 10) == 2 || parseInt($('#tipo_field').val(), 10) == 3
  }
}
```